# How do I see the number of rows processed in a data flow?

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

I have seen pictures of where the data flow tasks shows the number of rows processed in Visual Studio.

How do I get to see that?

[image]

Comment: Should happen automatically, if rows are in fact being transferred.

Answer (score 1):

In the view shown, the row counts would be shown automatically if any rows were in fact being transferred.   Looks like both of your datasources are running successfully and not outputting any rows.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on a line -> Enable Data Viewer